# Broadcast intents for bluetooth, wifi and ringer mode

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-intent, intentfilter, android-wifi

What are the intents that are broadcasted in the following events,

1. Wifi state change
2. Bluetooth state change
3. Ringer mode change

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For **Wifi state** changes:

[WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) ("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED")

> Broadcast intent action indicating
>   that Wi-Fi has been enabled, disabled,
>   enabling, disabling, or unknown. One
>   extra provides this state as an int.
>   Another extra provides the previous
>   state, if available.

WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION ("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE")

> Broadcast intent action indicating
>   that the state of Wi-Fi connectivity
>   has changed. One extra provides the
>   new state in the form of a NetworkInfo
>   object. If the new state is CONNECTED,
>   a second extra may provide the BSSID
>   of the access point, as a String.

WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION ("android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE")

> Broadcast intent action indicating
>   that a connection to the supplicant
>   has been established (and it is now
>   possible to perform Wi-Fi operations)
>   or the connection to the supplicant
>   has been lost. One extra provides the
>   connection state as a boolean, where
>   true means CONNECTED.

Also take a look at ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION ("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")

> A change in network connectivity has
>   occurred. A connection has either been
>   established or lost. The NetworkInfo
>   for the affected network is sent as an
>   extra; it should be consulted to see
>   what kind of connectivity event
>   occurred.
>
> If this is a connection that was the
>   result of failing over from a
>   disconnected network, then the
>   FAILOVER_CONNECTION boolean extra is
>   set to true.
>
> For a loss of connectivity, if the
>   connectivity manager is attempting to
>   connect (or has already connected) to
>   another network, the NetworkInfo for
>   the new network is also passed as an
>   extra. This lets any receivers of the
>   broadcast know that they should not
>   necessarily tell the user that no data
>   traffic will be possible. Instead, the
>   reciever should expect another
>   broadcast soon, indicating either that
>   the failover attempt succeeded (and so
>   there is still overall data
>   connectivity), or that the failover
>   attempt failed, meaning that all
>   connectivity has been lost.
>
> For a disconnect event, the boolean
>   extra EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY is set to
>   true if there are no connected
>   networks at all.

For **Bluetooth state** changes:

[BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) ("android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED")

> Broadcast Action: The state of the
>   local Bluetooth adapter has been
>   changed.
>   For example, Bluetooth has been turned
>   on or off.

and for **Ringer mode** changes:

AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION ("android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED")

> Sticky broadcast intent action
>   indicating that the ringer mode has
>   changed. Includes the new ringer mode.

Not a ringer mode change, but this can be good to have also AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_CHANGED_ACTION ("android.media.VIBRATE_SETTING_CHANGED")

> Broadcast intent action indicating
>   that the vibrate setting has changed.
>   Includes the vibrate type and its new
>   setting.

(Ops, got no rep so only 2 links... :( )