# Android - How to check internet Access, not just connectivity to wifi?

Tags: android, connection

I tried the below code to check whether my mobile is connected to a wireless network and it works well when I want to know if my mobile is connected to the network, but it fails to give information about the internet access ... something like "Pinging" any website.
Actually I followed many links but still no answer, so I'll be so thankful if anybody can help.

Thanks in Advance.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Toast t = new Toast(getApplicationContext());

    if (isInternetOn()) {
         // INTERNET IS AVAILABLE, DO STUFF..
         Toast.makeText(ConnectivityTestActivity.this,"Network is Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }
    else {
         // NO INTERNET AVAILABLE, DO STUFF..
        Toast.makeText(ConnectivityTestActivity.this,"No Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
}

public final boolean isInternetOn() {


    ConnectivityManager connec =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
    if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
    connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
    connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
    connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) {
    // MESSAGE TO SCREEN FOR TESTING (IF REQ)
    //Toast.makeText(this, connectionType + ” connected”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
    } else if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED  ) {

    return false;
    }
    return false;
    }}
```

**EDIT:**

Follow below link it contains a great answer for Ping google server and get result

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16458623/1239911

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually I used the same function `isInternetOn()` but I removed the connecting condition.
It had to check the status of connection if connected or not and if it is trying to connect. This didn't work for me, so I removed connecting status checking and then it worked.

Thanks for all replies.

```
public final boolean isInternetOn()
{
  ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)
    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

  // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
  if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
       connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED )
  {
    // MESSAGE TO SCREEN FOR TESTING (IF REQ)
    //Toast.makeText(this, connectionType + ” connected”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
  }
  else if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
    ||  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED  )
  {
    return false;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Just a note ... I used the above code from another question here in stackoverflow.com, we may use    'ConnectivityManager.Type_WIFI' or     'ConnectivityManager.Type_Mobile' instead of 0 & 1 in the getNetworkInfo()

Comment: Why did you even need the `else if` part? If we are not conected that means we are disconnected. Can you please let me know if there is any use of this `else if` part?

Comment: It might be CONNECTED, DISCONNECTED, CONNECTING, DISCONNECTING, SUSPENDED and UNKNOWN. You can check theses states in developer.android.com or when you click ctrl+space after (NetworkInfo.State.) in your code. I wish this can be helpful.

Comment: But in your case, if the `if` condition fails. The `else` condition will be evaluated, now wheather the `else` condition passes or fails in both cases we are returning `false`. Then why do we need `else` condition in above case? That was my point. Any ways Good Info in your last comment.

Comment: I see :) . Actually I want it to return false only when it is DISCONNECTED

Comment: Here is a good ping answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16458623/1239911

Answer (score 6):

see the sample:

```
public static boolean isWifiEnabled() {
    if ( !gWifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {

        if (mCanShowWifiToast) {
            new Thread(mWifiToastControl).start();
            G.gHandler.post(mNoWifiRunnable);
        }

        return false;
    } else {
        int linkspeed = gWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getLinkSpeed();
        if (linkspeed < 5) {
            if (mCanShowWifiToast) {
                new Thread(mWifiToastControl).start();
                G.gHandler.post(mNoWifiRunnable);
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use BroadcastReceivers that will trigger when the connection status change: there is a similar question with an answer: [Broadcast intents for bluetooth, wifi and ringer mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297647/broadcast-intents-for-bluetooth-wifi-and-ringer-mode)